# replace text in larger body between text, PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, substr

I have cobbled together enough code to find and replace text between specific phrases in a larger body of text, however I'm getting hung up on replacing ONLY that text. The below code finds it and replaces the whole very long string instead of only the portion i'm wanting to target. For example, if want to change "WRONG TAG = blah blah blah" in the middle of "Susie rides her bike down the street *WRONG TAG = blah blah blah*" to equal "Susie rides her bike down the street *RIGHT TAG BLAH BLAH BLAH*" Right now I'm wiping the whole thing out, only leaving "RIGHT TAG BLAH BLAH BLAH"

```
$text = mysqli_query($conn, "Select body from ReplaceTest");

$imageId = 'new tag = 787654323';

$search = "/[^$wrongTag](.*)[^<\/]/";
$replace = "$id";
$string = "<wrongTag:id=\" blah blah blah />";


 $newText = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);

 $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE T1
 SET body = '$newText'");
```

Comment: This is a regex issue.  Nothing to do with PHP or MySQL.  It's unclear how exactly the regex `$search` should be written though.  Can you give more examples and the expected outcome?

Comment: a very long paragraph with the phrase to be replaced, always beginning with "BAD TAG=" and ending with ">" to be replaced by a queried variable and string combo. It can be anywhere in the long paragraph. It's on a table and I'll have to roll through replacing based on the contents of the replaced tag.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: (Also an update without a where clause can cause unpleasant surprises.)

Comment: Currently just trying to work out the logic on a test table with one row -- that's why no where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
$newText = preg_replace('/<$wrongTag([^>]+)/', "<$rigthtag$1", $string);
```

Comment: this did the same as my other option... replaced the whole queried field "body" with only the string replacement. :/

Comment: @user1827601: Sorry, I don't get you. Could you edit your question with some input strings and expected result?